# Virtual destructor when using upcasting

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual-destructor

Everyone says that a destructor should be virtual when at least one of class methods is virtual.
My questions is, isn't it correct to say that a destructor should be virtual when using upcasting ?

```
class A {
public:

    ~A(){
        cout << "Destructor in A" << endl;
    }
};

class B: public A
{
public:

    ~B(){
        cout << "Destructor in B" << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    A* a = new B;
    cout << "Exiting main" << endl;
    delete a;
}
```

I don't have any virtual functions in this code, but if I don't make my base destructor virtual, it will not call B destructor. And yes I know that is pointless to use ucpasting if I don't have virtual functions.

Thank you.

Comment: @Neil: Is `A *a = new B` not an up-cast?

Comment: @Oli I don't see a cast there, do you?

Comment: There's a corollary to this advice: never derive from a class unless it has at least 1 virtual function.  I would add: never derive from a class unless it has a virtual destructor.  In either case, the "base class" was probably not intended as a "base class" in the first place.

Comment: @Neil: I see one.  It's implicit, but it's a cast for sure.

Comment: @ André Caron: i like your advice, its better +1

Comment: @André Caron Only derive if the base class has a `public virtual` destructor *or* a `protected non-virtual` destructor.

Comment: @AndréCaron: Counterexample: `std::binary_function< ..., ... >` Inheritance isn't always about runtime polymorphism.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> a destructor should be virtual when at least one of class methods is virtual

This is a rule of thumb which arises from the fact that when you use virtual functions you are using runtime polymorphism and are more likely to run into situations were you need to destroy a class that may be of a derived type when all you have is a pointer to its base class subobject.

When you destroy a derived object by using `delete` on a pointer to the base class a virtual destructor is necessary in the base class to avoid *undefined behavior*. This is the only time a virtual destructor is necessary and the guideline is intended to help avoid this situation arising.

[Herb Sutter](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill18.htm) advocated the guideline that base class destructors (i.e. destructors for classes designed to be inherited from) should be either `public` and `virtual` or `protected` and non-`virtual`. This allows the possibility that you don't intend a base class to be a point in the inheritance hierarchy which is used for deletion of derived objects and you want to enforce that this doesn't occur unintentionally.

Of course, if you have a pure value class which isn't to be a base class, there is little you can do to stop people deriving from it anyway and then deleting derived class via pointer to base.

Answer (score 13):

You need a virtual destructor if you ever delete a derived object via a base pointer. That's it, in a nutshell.

Comment: While this is more accurate, the rule OP mentioned is just as good considering that it's unlikely you'll delete objects this way if the base class has no virtual methods.

Comment: But if you write a library it may not be you that is doing the deleting and thus this explanation is not sufficient. You also need to understand why you may be accessing an object via a pointer to a base class (without that information this answer is not sufficient to explain the situation).

Answer (score 1):

You should always declare a virtual destructor when one of the class methods is virtual if you are deleting a pointer to a derived class, but the pointer type is the base class then base class must have a virtual destructor in this case or the compiler doesn't (or isn't supposed to) know what destructor it should call (and it's UB).

Comment: Most people wouldn't consider _undefined behavior_ as being an acceptable example of "works perfectly fine". A virtual destructor is necessary if you `delete` a derived class using a pointer to a base class regardless of any other considerations.

Comment: Also, what is a "virtual class"?

Comment: @Charles: I tried grasping the idea a bit better, is what I edited in correct? @Neil Butterworth: Woops, I chose my words better now :)

Comment: -1: It might "work", but people probably expect to have `virtual ~A()` when they write a new class that derives from `A`.

Comment: @Charles Bailey: Unfortunately **most people** (statistically) will consider it acceptable which is very sad.

Comment: I changed my answer to ignore the fact that it __might__ be legal in some occasions and suggest to always make it virtual when one of the class methods is virtual instead.

Comment: @nightcracker: It's not "what destructor it should call", it's just "anything (bad) can happen". For example, if the derived class has `operator new()` overloaded you're screwed big time even regardless of possible destructor issues.

Comment: I'm sorry, but reason #1 is a terrible reason.  You can't possibly know what base classes' destructors are going to implement (even if you can now, you can't guarantee this won't change).

Comment: @André Caron: Perhaps you misread (or I miswrote) what I said. I'm trying to say that if I derive a class B from class A and I need a resource that should be destructed I can't use the destrucor unless it's declared virtual.

Comment: @nightcracker: But what you've said in your last comment is just not true. When you destroy a derived object correctly, the base class destructor will be called on the base class sub-object whether or not its destructor is declared virtual. The only issue is that calling `delete` on a pointer to base where the base class destructor isn't virtual won't correctly destroy a derived object.

Comment: @Charles Bailey: Alright, I'm new to C++, so please don't mind me if I'm garbaging around sometimes. Changed the answer again.

Answer (score 1):

The destructor should be made `virtual` if you are doing something useful (memory deallocation etc.) in the derived class destructor.

By the way, It's **advisable** (not mandatory) to have virtual destructor when a `class` contains a `virtual` method.

Comment: The problem is that when you write the base class, you technically *don't know* if the derived class will *ever* do something useful.

Comment: @Andre, agree with that, but in such case always the destructor will be virtual. It's a good practice to be aware of what other derived destructors are doing in hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

It's incorrect:

```
shared_ptr<A> ptr = make_shared<B>();
```

does up cast and deletes `B` correctly. Just follow @Neil Butterworth's answer.